# Hidden Input is not posting while clicking on the menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, smarty

I have a menu on top of my page built using UL LI tags.  I have a hidden input tag linked to menu using JQuery event. When clicked, option can be seen in the console.log but is not being posting to a PHP scritp. I need help here, can someone put me in the right direction

Here is HTML

```
<form name="mainmenu" id="mainmenu" action="index.php" method="post">
    <div id='content'>
       <div id='jqxMenu'>
            <ul>
                <li>Maintanence
                    <ul style='width: 180px;'>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addCategory">Add Category</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addSubCategory">Add Sub-category</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Process Order
                    <ul style='width: 180px;'>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addShipOrder">Ship Order</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addChangeOrder">Change Order Status</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Reports
                    <ul style='width: 180x;'>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addOrderStation">Orders by station</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addOrderDate">Orders by date</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addPendingOrder">Pending Orders</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-val="Logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div><input id="menuoption" type="hidden" name="menuoption"></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

here is JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
          $('#jqxMenu a').on('click', function() {
           $('#menuoption').val($(this).data('val'));
       });
    });
```

here is PHP script

```
    if (isset($_POST['menu_index']))
    {
        if ($_POST['menu_index'] == 'Logout')
        {
            $smarty->display("login.tpl");  
            exit();            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your form element is called `menuoption` and your PHP script refers to `menu_index`

Comment: yes, I made it visible and can see the values there but post is not firing when make it hidden

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding.  Where is `menu_index` in your HTML code?  Can you show all your code?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, sorry that a typo. but the problem is that the POST is not firing so it is not evening reaching at the PHP script

Comment: Where is your form being submitted?  Is there a `submit` button somewhere or are you calling `.submit()` with script somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you use wrong name of input in your PHP script. Are you sure you want to look for $_POST["menu_index"] instead of $_POST["menuoption"]?

In case, that the index in PHP script is correct, try to dump $_POST and check for values in it.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and you will easily see what you have and what you do not have

EDIT: you are not submitting the form

Try to edit your jQuery code like that

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
      $('#jqxMenu a').on('click', function() {
       $('#menuoption').val($(this).data('val'));
       $('#mainmenu').submit();
   });
});
```

this will trigger submit of the form.

Comment: There is nothing in the post. Firebug is not even showing anything in POST